# Demo: how to import this micromodal library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm trying to implement this in my React Web app. However, I have no idea how to import it. https://micromodal.now.sh/

I have tried npm install micromodal --save and then downloaded the cdn link to the min.js file and added it to my project as well as the demo CSS: https://gist.github.com/ghosh/4f94cf497d7090359a5c9f81caf60699

On the file that I want to use it, I tried:

```
<a data-micromodal-trigger="modal-1">
//some image
</a>
```

And then did:

```
    <div id="modal-1">
//contents of example modal
    </div>
```

Can someone create a mini react project that shows how to implement this library on the click of a link. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the modal markup and styles. You can get them [**here**](https://gist.github.com/ghosh/4f94cf497d7090359a5c9f81caf60699#file-micromodal-html).

Just create a [**`micromodal.css`**](https://gist.github.com/ghosh/4f94cf497d7090359a5c9f81caf60699#file-micromodal-css) and import it in your Component.

You can then trigger the modal to open by calling:

```
MicroModal.show('modal-id');
```

Give this a try:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MicroModal from "micromodal"; // es6 module
import "./styles.css";
import "./micromodal.css";

function App() {
  MicroModal.init();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <button onClick={() => MicroModal.show("modal-1")}>Open Modal</button>

      <div class="modal micromodal-slide" id="modal-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal__overlay" tabindex="-1" data-micromodal-close>
          <div
            class="modal__container"
            role="dialog"
            aria-modal="true"
            aria-labelledby="modal-1-title"
          >
            <header class="modal__header">
              <h2 class="modal__title" id="modal-1-title">
                Micromodal
              </h2>
              <button
                class="modal__close"
                aria-label="Close modal"
                data-micromodal-close
              />
            </header>
            <main class="modal__content" id="modal-1-content">
              <p>
                Try hitting the <code>tab</code> key and notice how the focus
                stays within the modal itself. Also, <code>esc</code> to close
                modal.
              </p>
            </main>
            <footer class="modal__footer">
              <button class="modal__btn modal__btn-primary">Continue</button>
              <button
                class="modal__btn"
                data-micromodal-close
                aria-label="Close this dialog window"
              >
                Close
              </button>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

---

> Here's a [**CodeSandbox Sample**](https://codesandbox.io/s/micro-modal-eg-6j2y7) for your ref.

Comment: Ok, so do I need the .js file?
Also, how can I trigger the modal from an <a>  (anchor)

Comment: Create a method `const openModal = () => MicroModal.show("modal-1");` and then call it `onClick` of the link:  `<a href="javascript:;" onClick={openModal}>
        Trigger Modal
      </a>` I've updated the codesand for the same. Not sure what you mean by *do I need a .js file*.

Comment: Thank you!!
Do I need to do anything with this file? https://unpkg.com/micromodal/dist/micromodal.min.js

Comment: Since you're using React, you can install it via `npm` and then I'm already referencing it in the `App.js` here: `import MicroModal from "micromodal";`. So you don't need `unpkg.com/micromodal/dist/micromodal.min.js`

Comment: Alright thank you so much for your help!! It works now

Comment: Hi Sidd, last thing can you help me with. How can I send some data into the onclick "openModal" const. i.e. I want to send the id to open the modal with which is {projects.id}. 

For e.g.       
<a className="cell" href="javascript:;" onClick={() => MicroModal.show({projects.id})}>
However, I am receiving an parsing error: unexpected token, expecting ,

Comment: I'd request you to please create a separate question regarding that to keep this thread focused.